# Number of arithmetic sequence terms relatively prime to $N$ is $\varphi(N)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> If $a$ is relatively prime to $N$ show that the number of terms of the arithmetic progression $x, x+a, x+2a, ..., x+(n-1)a$ which are prime to $N$ is $\varphi(N)$, where $x$ is any integer.

$$\gcd(a,N)= 1$$
If $a$ is a factor of $x$ then the number of primes in the sequence would be zero. So $a$ is not a term in the factorization of $x$.
I can't proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First prove that $\{0\cdot a,1\cdot a,2\cdot a,\cdots,(n-1)\cdot a\}$ is a complete residue class $\pmod{N}$. In order to prove this, suppose otherwise, then $i\cdot a\equiv j\cdot a\pmod{N}$ for some $i\ne j\pmod{N}$. Can you continue?